# Basic authentication in project using Cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, basic-authentication

I have an MVC project using Cookie Authentication, but I want a single action to use basic authentication.

My problem is, that if the basic authentication fails, the user is redirected to the login page, specified in the cookie setup, instead of being issued a challenge.

My basic authentication code is from this page: http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/

How do I prevent this redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

to the authentication attribute, will prevent the server from returning the login page.